# How to receive sms messages on raspberry pi

Tags: text, sms, raspberry-pi, message, twilio

I recently set up a Twilio account and got a registered Twilio phone number. Is there a way that I can get those messages on my raspberry pi? My intent is to display those messages on a LED screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to either expose the RasPi to the public internet (so Twilio's SMS callback could reach it), or use some proxy service in between.

The proxy would capture the inbound callback, then the RasPi could either poll, or use some better method, to check for new messages (meaning, the RasPi does not have to be on the public internet).

[Temboo](https://temboo.com/) also has a set of tools that make it easier to build IoT applications that interact with APIs. I believe they can act like the proxy I describe.

Comment: Tim, I appreciate the response. I have never personally set up a proxy service. Do you know of any recommended tutorials to demonstrate?

Comment: @DjBlackwell Sorry I missed this - ngrok is the simplest thing to use at the moment.